# After deploying a Javascript Microsoft Botframework template via Azure the provided URL returns an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, restify

After following all the steps from start to finish provided by Microsoft (Tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 ) I've setup the continuous deployment via GIT which works fine.

I've been able to run the code on my localhost and Bot Framework Emulator without any issues. I've also been able to run the bot using the web chat channel iframe provided on the Azure platform.
( https:// webchat.botframework.com/embed/{your-bot}?s={secret})

Lastly I'm also able to run the bot using the "test in web chat" option via Azure.

However, when I try to use the URL provided by azure to test my bot I get the following:

https://{your-domain}.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
`{"code":"MethodNotAllowed","message":"GET is not allowed"}`

And from https://{your-domain}.azurewebsites.net

`{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}`

I've scoured the internet trying to find a solution, all the solutions that I found are using the old version of the framework and point towards a server.get method not being present in index.js.

If there's any more information that I can provide please let me know.

Here's the code from index.js

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

// index.js is used to setup and configure your bot

// Import required packages
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services. See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, ConversationState, InputHints, MemoryStorage, UserState } = require('botbuilder');
const { FlightBookingRecognizer } = require('./dialogs/flightBookingRecognizer');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { DialogAndWelcomeBot } = require('./bots/dialogAndWelcomeBot');
const { MainDialog } = require('./dialogs/mainDialog');

// the bot's booking dialog
const { BookingDialog } = require('./dialogs/bookingDialog');
const BOOKING_DIALOG = 'bookingDialog';

// Note: Ensure you have a .env file and include LuisAppId, LuisAPIKey and LuisAPIHostName.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log
    // NOTE: In production environment, you should consider logging this to Azure
    //       application insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    // Send a message to the user
    const onTurnErrorMessage = `Sorry, it looks like something went wrong!`;
    await context.sendActivity(onTurnErrorMessage, onTurnErrorMessage, InputHints.ExpectingInput);
    // Clear out state
    await conversationState.delete(context);
};

// Define a state store for your bot. See https://aka.ms/about-bot-state to learn more about using MemoryStorage.
// A bot requires a state store to persist the dialog and user state between messages.

// For local development, in-memory storage is used.
// CAUTION: The Memory Storage used here is for local bot debugging only. When the bot
// is restarted, anything stored in memory will be gone.
const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
const conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);

// If configured, pass in the FlightBookingRecognizer.  (Defining it externally allows it to be mocked for tests)
const { LuisAppId, LuisAPIKey, LuisAPIHostName } = process.env;
const luisConfig = { applicationId: LuisAppId, endpointKey: LuisAPIKey, endpoint: `https://${ LuisAPIHostName }` };

const luisRecognizer = new FlightBookingRecognizer(luisConfig);

// Create the main dialog.
const bookingDialog = new BookingDialog(BOOKING_DIALOG);
const dialog = new MainDialog(luisRecognizer, bookingDialog);
const bot = new DialogAndWelcomeBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo test your bot, see: https://aka.ms/debug-with-emulator`);
});

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bot Framework `/api/messages` endpoint is configured to accept `POST` requests. Navigating to `https://{your-domain}.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` is a `GET` request, which is why are getting the "Resource not found" response. The "Resource not found" response actually tells you that your bot is running. If the web app wasn't running or the initial deployment failed, you would see a "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" message. As long as Test in Web Chat works, you are good to go!

If you want to add a static HTML page to your server, there are a few changes I would recommend adding to your bot.

**Direct Line Token Endpoint**

First, you should add another endpoint to your bot to generate a Direct Line Token. Here is a basic implementation. For more details I recommend you take a look at the [Direct Line Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation.

```
// DirectLine Token
server.post('/directline/token', async (req, res) => {

    const id = (req.body && req.body.id)? `dl_${req.body.id}`: `dl_default_user`

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.directLineSecret}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         },
        url: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', 
        data: {
            user: { id }
        }
    };

    try {
        const { data } = await axios(options);
        res.send(data);
    } catch ({ message }) {
        res.status(403);
        res.send({ message });
    }
});
```

**Serve Static Files**
Next, create a public file in your root directory and add a new endpoint to your bot with the Restify `serveStatic` plugin. Take a look at the [Restify Plugin](http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#servestatic) documentation for more details.

```
server.get('/*', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
    directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    default: 'index.html'
}));
```

**index.html**
Finally, in your public directory, create an `index.html` and add the following code. It is configured to request a token from your `/directline/token` endpoint and render an instance of Web Chat.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>
      (async function () {

        const res = await fetch('/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
          directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks for the confirmation.

However, I would like to know if it's possible to get it running in the browser via a get request. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @Beast I updated my answer to include hosting a static Web Chat instance. Also, marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: Marking as answered now. This is exactly what I was looking for. +1